# Send request to soap server using php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

There are three interfaces in the soap server i am communicating with.
I want to communicate with the following interface.
Below is the request code from soap ui.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rint="http://rint.crm.ailk.com" xmlns:xsd="http://bo.out.intframe.ailk.com/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://bo.partner.out.lint.abc.prbinfo.com/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rint:balanceTransfer>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rint:commonHeader>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:acceptChannel>?</xsd:acceptChannel>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:acceptType>?</xsd:acceptType>
         </rint:commonHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rint:balanceTransferReq>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:balanceRecord>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd1:amount>?</xsd1:amount>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd1:hold1>?</xsd1:hold1>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd1:operationType>?</xsd1:operationType>               
            </xsd1:balanceRecord>
         </rint:balanceTransferReq>
      </rint:balanceTransfer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
<?php
//Initiate SOAP connection with SOAP server
$wsdl = "wsdl_link_from_my_api_provider_which_is_now_on_their_private_network";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
//set parameters
$params = array("ChannelID" => "0001", "AccessType" => "14");
$params1 = array(
                  "amount" => "100",
                  "hold1" => "3099",
                  "operationType" => "1"    
                 );
//send request and receive response
$response = $client->__soapCall("balanceTransferReq", $params, $params1);
?>
```

I am getting error from the server , as i dont know the correct way to send parameters in this case.

Comment: SoapClient has a method that allows you to list all types and their parameters: you can do something like `echo "<pre>"; $client->__getTypes(); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: __soapCall accepts only one array for SOAP parameters.  Try to merge $params and $params1, while reflecting the xml structure in the final parameters array.

Comment: @softius I tried merging them, but still no change,  there is one parent parameter in above xml code i.e. balanceRecord, how to handle that one?